# Get type which instantiates a form, from within that form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

I have a WinForms Application which for instance has 2 different Types of objects and one common form.

```
Public Class A:
{
   private MyForm formA = new MyForm();
   public void ShowForm()
   {
      formA.ShowDialog();
   }
}

Public Class B:
{
   private MyForm formB = new MyForm();

   public void ShowForm()
   {
      formB.ShowDialog();
   }

}

Public class MyForm : Form
{
}
```

Is there a way to reflectively tell what class is displaying MyForm from within the MyForm Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, well, not without walking the strack trace which is at best a hack.

Change your form constructor to take a `Type` parameter and have the parent class pass it's own type:

`new MyForm(typeof(B));`

Comment: hmm thats what I was afraid of, guess ill change around my constructors then.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, but **its a hack and you shouldn't do it!**

That said you can do this via the `StackTrace` class:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
if (stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name == "A")
{
    // Class A called us
}
```

We ask the stack trace for the first stack frame (the 0th stack frame is the current one) because we are after the method that called this method.  You can use other properties of the `MethodBase` instance returned by the `GetMethod` call to find out other information such as the method name.

The **much better** way of doing this is instead to modify the constructor to accept additional arguments to modify the behaviour of the form.  *These arguments should encapsulate the behaviour of the form* for example you may wish to pass a boolean flag indicating whether certain controls are disabled, or a text field to customise the forms title.

You shouldn't have the form change its behaviour based on the caller as this makes it more difficult to re-use the form in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to MyForm in which the containing type is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing the form from some sort of control, call ShowDialog passing the calling control as the owner parameter:

```
formA.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then within the MyForm class you can check the Owner property to see who called it and get the type of the caller

```
Owner.GetType();
```